# Embarcadero refuses reinstallation of C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder-6

I have a serious problem right now.

As a freelance developer I am maintaining a very large project (500.000+ lines of code) of my customer which was written in an old version of C++ Builder.

Years ago I purchased an Enterprise License of Borland C++ Builder 6 and that was the IDE I used to manage this project.

Every time when Windows is updated, C++ Builder required to be re-registered. The last couple of times this meant: Write an E-Mail to Embarcadero, beg for pardon, be nice, wait a couple of days until they increased the Registration maximum.

This time they refused this... WHAT.THE.HELL?

Embarcadero is literally killing their own customers, for absolutly no reason!

What can I do in such a situation?

Upgrade is not an option, the project is far too large (I have several newer licenses of Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++ Builder and have already tried a migration).

Is there a way to purchase a version of Builder6 that does not require this online registration? Or are there any other work arounds?

regards, Herwig

[image]

Comment: "*Is there a way to purchase a version of Builder6 that does not require this online registration?*" - no such version exists. And you need a subscription now to increase the registration limit any further. See https://www.reddit.com/r/delphi/comments/byy7ku/no_more_registration_limit_increase/ and also https://blogs.embarcadero.com/from-the-gm-new-updates-and-changes-to-the-registration-bumps-policy/

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau for your answer. One of the comments on reddit exaclty points it out: "IMHO, this is just the sound of the casket closing". I regret every penny I have ever spent on Embarcadero because they only used the money to optimize the outwitting of their customers instead of fixing bugs. This is such a shame...